# Using new on an anonymous object with a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, class, function, object, prototype

Can i do :

```
var foo = new Foo;
```

with :

```
var Foo = { prototype : { } };
```

As i would do with :

```
var Foo = function() { };
```

?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm is there some problem behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

The point is that the `prototype` property is a property of the constructor, in this case `Foo`. If you create an object using literal syntax such as

```
var foo = { prototype: {} };
```

you have the property assigned to the object, not the constructor.

That's a difference, and hence automatic lookup on the prototype object won't work when using this literal syntax.

If you want to work with the prototype, you *HAVE* to use the constructor syntax as follows:

```
var Foo = function () {};
Foo.prototype.foo = 'bar';

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.foo); // => 'bar'
```

As discussed in the comments, it also does not work if you try to assign a `constructor` property to the object in literal syntax: It again only works when using *true* prototyping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could i manually add it to the constructor, like : { constructor : { prototype: {} } }; I don't need to do it, just want to understand the mechanics.

Comment: I don't know, as I have not tried it, but you can easily check this for yourself ;-). PS: Just tried it, and no, it does not work.

Comment: Okay, i just thought someone knew it :P

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly ... :-)

Comment: PS: If this answer answered your question, it would be nice if you could mark it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No. The value after the [`new` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2) must be something constructable (an object with `[[construct]]`), like functions are. You cannot use arbitrary objects.

To inherit from an arbitrary object, use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var fooProto = { … };

var foo = Object.create(fooProto);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, ìn `new X` `X` must evaluate to a function.

> Thanks for your answer. Could i manually add it to the constructor,
>   like : { constructor : { prototype: {} } }; I don't need to do it,
>   just want to understand the mechanics.

The mechanic is that it must be a function, the `.constructor` or `.prototype` properties do not matter at all and you can in fact `new X` even if you `delete` the `.prototype` property of `X` - all you need literally need is for `X` to be a function.

Answer (score 0):

**NO.**
As in

```
var Foo = { prototype : { } };
```

Foo is an object not a function. You can do "new" only on **function**

Answer (score 0):

Small hint:

```
function Fun() {};

var anonym = {};
var fun = new Fun;

anonym.prototype.p = function() {};
Fun.prototype.p = function(){};

'p' in anonym;  // false  
'p' in fun;     // true  (engine looks for properties in constructor's prototype object)

anonym.constructor.prototype.p = function() {};
'p' in anonym;  // true
```